# How can I rotate these instances along a curve in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, procedural

I am trying to make a procedural bridge, is their a way that I can rotate these planks along the curve.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `Curve to Points` node, because it will give you the rotation you want right away.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `Curve tangent` node and the `align euler to vector`

[image: geometry nodes]

[image: nodes result]

Answer (score 2):

you need an align eula to vector node and plug in tangent or normals.
for that you need curve to points instead of resample
[image]

Comment: You don't need the Euler to vector in this setup, you can just plug the "Rotation" output of "Curve to Points" into the "Rotation" input of "Instance on Points."

Answer (score 0):

This method worked well.
Objects are randomly extracted from the collection.

[image]
[image]