# How to get the rotation on each point right?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a basic curve with instances of curve circles on its points.

I'm trying to get the rotation of each instance facing the direction of the curve. Think of creating the shape of a pipe with the little circles.

I know that I control that via the `Rotation` connector. What I don't know is how to get the correct rotation of the point. I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, a duplicate of [How can I rotate these instances along a curve in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259156) and [How to orient a point to the next one with geometry node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228629)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Curve to points* node like this:

[image]