# Geometry Nodes Rotation Problem on Mesh Spline Circle

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm currently 5 days into geometry nodes and I'm having a problem here.

I'm trying to make an array modifier that goes in a circular motion with a mesh spline.

[image]

But when I try to rotate it to it's position, it just looks wrong. but when I replaced it with a Mesh Circle Node, it works. But I want to make it with the circle Mesh Spline I made.

[image]

[image]

Any thoughts?

Here's the full nodes

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu3Ov.png Full Nodes]

Comment: Please insert your images directly into your question rather than making us click on links to see them! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi, william, done for you, but do check out @JohnEason 's link

Answer (score 1):

Unless yours is a deliberate exercise in the maths, maybe some elaboration of this starting-point will do it for you?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259156/?

Comment: @quellenform and of quite a few others, if we search...  OK, let's tidy up.